# How can I set dataless areas of a hist2d plot to the zero-value color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm tracking a subject's gaze over a specified area of a computer screen.  I'm constructing gaze heatmaps using pyplot's `hist2d` function.

Here's a simple example:

```
figure()
hist2d(xval, yval, bins=1000)
xlim([-6, 6])
ylim([-4.5, 4.5])
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a significant area outside of the range of my data.  However, I would like to set this area to the blue indicative of a zero-value.

My first attempt using `imshow` can be seen here:

```
figure()
imshow(np.array([[0] * 8] * 12), extent=[-6, 6, -4.5, 4.5])
hist2d(xval, yval, bins=1000)
xlim([-6, 6])
ylim([-4.5, 4.5])
```

[image]

This sort of works, but leaves an ugly vertical line at the boundary of my data's range.

**My questions are as follows:**

1. Is there a way to fill the figure with the zero-value blue while avoiding the `imshow` call
2. If not, how can I hide the vertical line?

Comment: White area is intentional because no data is essentially null, not 0. I think the best solution would be to extend the data you are plotting.

Comment: @sashkello, yes, I realize the white area is null, hence my question.  I don't see how I could extend the data without denaturing it.  My question *is*, "how do I extend it".

Comment: If it is a question of visualization, I don't see a point in getting into much trouble with it - just have a temporary modified data set for plotting.

Comment: @shashkello, I understand, but my problem is that I don't see how I would go about modifying the dataset.  Histograms count occurrences of data, so in order for there to be a zero-value, there needs to **not** be data.  I believe that `hist2d` whites out all coordinates outside of the maximum value in each dimension.

In the meantime, I've figured it out.  I need only mess with the `range` kwarg.

Comment: @sashkello Modifying data just for plotting starts to run it to ethical issues _real_ fast.  In this case padding out with zeros may be reasonable, but it is still a bad attitude to have.  The first responsibility of a graph is to be _accurate_, everything else is secondary.

Comment: @blz You might want to look into using other color maps, `cubehelix` is participatory nice and might work for your data.

Comment: @tcaswell, Thanks for the suggestion!  These graphs were prototypes, but I was thinking of looking at other color maps because the small values aren't readily visible.  Your suggestion is most welcome, and I'll check out `cubehelix`!  I also second your opinion on transforming data for plotting purposes -- one should transform data in order answer a question -- the graph should make that answer legible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out.  It's actually rather simple:  one just needs to manipulate the `range` kwarg.

```
figure()
#imshow(np.array([[0] * 8] * 12), extent=[-6, 6, -4.5, 4.5])
hist2d(xval, yval, bins=1000, range=np.array([(-6, 6), (-4.5, 4.5)]))
xlim([-6, 6])
ylim([-4.5, 4.5])
```

[image]